# Overriding a class file from a library JAR in a Java web app

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jar, classpath

In my Java web app, I have these files:

```
/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/Foo.class
/WEB-INF/lib/example.jar <-- contains the class "com.example.Foo"
```

Will the class defined in the `classes` directory be used instead of the class defined in `example.jar`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer depends upon your container, it is container dependent. In general, /WEB-INF/classes is preferred to classes in a jar file in WEB-INF/lib.

For [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html), the order is the following:

Therefore, from the perspective of a web application, class or resource loading looks in the following repositories, in this order:

1. Bootstrap classes of your JVM
2. System class loader classes
3. /WEB-INF/classes of your web application
4. /WEB-INF/lib/*.jar of your web application
5. Common class loader classes

But if you're using a different container, you need to consult the documentation for that server.

Comment: And I think any classes in example.jar still get Foo.class from the jar file.

Comment: @AmirRaminfar No, it should always use the same version of the class, otherwise madness ensues.

Comment: So you are saying Bar.class in `example.jar` that imports Foo.class will load Foo.class in `web-inf/classes` ? Because that doesn't sound right and it would be a security restriction I am sure.

Comment: @AmirRaminfar Are you saying that Baz.class (in classes) which needs Foo.class (in classes) which calls Bar.class (in example.jar, and depends upon Foo.class) will use the Foo.class from example.jar instead of the one that is already loaded? I think not.

Comment: No I am talking about Bar.class in the jar file! `example.jar!/com/example/Bar.class` will load Foo.class in `example.jar/com/example/Foo.class`

Comment: Only one way to test this. But I doubt if what you say is true because then I can load SecureClass.class in my webapp and basically overtake everything.

Comment: @AmirRaminfar Well, it's your webapp...if you want to compromise your own web app that's OK with me...

Answer (score 7):

So there is only one way to find out. I wrote a test :)

```
├── example
│   ├── example.iml
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   └── java
│       │       └── test
│       │           ├── Bar.java
│       │           └── Foo.java
│       └── test
│           └── java
│               └── testexample
│                   └── TestFoo.java
├── pom.xml
├── test.iml
└── web
    ├── pom.xml
    ├── src
    │   ├── main
    │   │   └── java
    │   │       └── test
    │   │           └── Foo.java
    │   └── test
    │       └── java
    │           └── junittest
    │               └── TestFooInWeb.java
    └── web.iml

16 directories, 11 files
```

My finding was that in `TestFoo.java` prints

```
Hello from example.jar
Hello from example.jar
```

And for `TestFooInWeb.java` prints

```
Hello from web app
Hello from web app
```

Both tests have this in the test class:

```
public class TestFooInWeb/TestFoo {
    @Test
    public void testHello() {
        System.out.println(new Foo().sayHello());
    }

    @Test
    public void testHelloFromBar() {
        new Bar().sayHelloForFoo();
    }
}
```

So all at the end, I stand corrected. You apprantly can load a completely different class and all Jar files will use that new class. This makes sense because the `ClassLoader` will first look at the classes directory. I am not sure if I agree with it because it sounds suspicious and I can overwrite security classes.

Comment: Very detailed experiment, thank you!  I'm pretty sure you can't override the core Java classes, though.  So, for example, you couldn't create a `java.lang.String` class and have it do something nasty.  Btw, what are those ".iml" files??

Comment: Those .iml files are intellij ide. And you are right you cannot over write system classes. If you look at what Mathew wrote, the order is system classpath then web classpath.

Comment: confused.  what is SayHelloForFoo()?  Where's your example.jar?  Where's this 'classes' directory?