# rich:pickList selection buttons arrow in right-to-left language direction

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I am using richfaces 3.3.2 and application is run in English and Arabic Languages. I am facing problem in  tag. In right-to-left mode the master,child list switch places but the pointing arrows in selection controls do not rotate accordingly.

currently i have set its direction="ltr" in style but might need proper solution.

I took screen shot but cannot upload as i am newbie

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, although I am using Richfaces 4.x. One possible solution I tried is to wrap the **rich:pickList** with span or div and set

```
dir="ltr"
```

Hope it was not helpful.

Also check https://community.jboss.org/thread/197043

Update: I could finally solved the issue :)

1. Create a new Java class org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PickListRenderer in your project. Use the source of current richfaces version. 
2. Replace in method encodeEnd()

```
responseWriter.writeAttribute("style","width: 1px; position: absolute; left: -32767px;",null);
```

by

```
responseWriter.writeAttribute("style", "visibility:hidden;", null);
```

This replaces the style of button created above the list in **rich:pickList** to *visibility:hidden*.

Please note your container as well. I use Tomcat, which read classes under /WEB-INF/classes before /WEB-INF/lib/*.jar [[Overriding a class file from a library JAR in a Java web app]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362319/overriding-a-class-file-from-a-library-jar-in-a-java-web-app)