# Edit gradle dependency .class file

Tags: gradle, java-8

I have a gradle dependency   `compile group: 'org.drools', name: 'drools-compiler', version: '7.0.0.Final'`

I want to update the class file `org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl` in it and run my java application with the updated one.

How is it possible?

Comment: what have you tried so far? Please show us your efforts.

Comment: I have removed the package from the .jar file, and then added the packages source code in my application as java code and updated the source code.

Comment: I think you could just do it, i.e. copy class, compile as usual, add the jar compile dependency and at runtime your class will be loaded first. Did you try that? (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/8362348/1063673 for web apps). PLEASE NOTE: I DO NOT RECOMMEND TO OVERWRITE LIBRARY CLASSES!

Comment: I just want to put sysouts to find out the values getting passed to those files.

Comment: This is usually done with a debugger breakpoint step-by-step code execution.

Comment: I gave debug pointers there but, its not going to the place where I gave debug pointer.

Comment: And I am not able to see the value of the fields